# How do I connect to a dishwasher bushing?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher, drain-waste-vent

I just bought a new dishwasher for a newly renovated house that I just bought.
I am trying to install it myself.

My sink drain pipe has one of these sticking out the side above the U pipe thingy like the bottom right most example.[image: Dishwasher bushing]

Do I just go to town on the end of that with a hacksaw and clamp on the drain hose?

**Edit:**
My sink drain looks like so with the bushing circled. I do not believe there is a hole on it.
[image: Bad drawing]

Comment: Apparently you are not in the US. In the US we use a tailpiece with a DW takeoff. Not sure what the standard is where your from.

Comment: This is a Standard ABS fitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Do I just go to town on the end of that with a hacksaw and clamp on the drain hose?"

Yes.  The end is capped so that it can be installed without being connected to anything.  Leaving it uncapped would leave it open for leaks if you were to fill the drainpipe.

Just cut off the end as near to the cap as you can reasonable fit a saw, and slip the hose over it.  For added security, use a hose clamp to secure it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. I cut off the tip of the bushing and then I trimmed the drainage hose to the 5/8ths section and clamped that on with a hose clamp. No leaks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to measure the outside of the barbed fitting, then measure the inside of the dishwasher hose. If the hose is the same or slightly smaller, cut the end off of the hosebarb fitting attached to your pipe. You want the barbed part to be as long as possible, so cut very close to the end. Place a hose clamp on the hose, and attach your hose to the fitting.Tighten the clamp. Run the dishwasher and check for leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen the fitting you show, but I don't think you can use that. The hole in it seems very small.

You need to change the "Tailpiece" from the sink drain to one like this.
[image] This way it places the DW drain before the trap (U shaped pipe). If you do not place it before the trap, sewer gases will escape into the DW.

Also form the DW hose to loop up from the connection before it goes down into the DW. That will prevent water from backing up into the DW if the sink should back up.

Comment: That's overkill.  No need to re-plumb the entire drain.

Comment: This tailpiece replaces the original tailpiece. There is no re-plumbing involved. It is the standard in the US.